# Angular routing incorrect when using ModuleWithProviders

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The following works as intended, when the user navigates to /onboarding they get the correct path.

> app-routing

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'onboarding',
    loadChildren: 'app/onboarding/onboarding.module#OnboardingModule',
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

> onboarding-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OnboardingComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OnboardingRoutingModule { }
```

> onboarding.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    OnboardingRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [OnboardingComponent]
})
export class OnboardingModule {}
```

The problem arises when I update the `OnboardingModule` to use `ModuleWithProviders`, when the user navigates to `/onboarding` they are redirected to `/onboarding/home`

> Updated onboarding module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [OnboardingComponent]
})
export class OnboardingModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: RootOnboardingModule,
      providers: [],
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OnboardingModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    OnboardingRoutingModule,
    // StoreModule.forFeature('onboard', reducers),
    // EffectsModule.forFeature([OnboardingEffects]),
  ],
})
export class RootOnboardingModule {}
```

Comment: Did you try calling `OnBoardingModule.forRoot()` in the highest import module?

Comment: @MikeTung the module is lazy loaded and there is a `stati forRoot()` on the OnboardingModule - should there be another `forRoot()` somewhere else?